# Is there any way to put a single result from a CSV into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm making a program in school where users are quizzed on certain topics and their results are saved into a csv file. I've managed to print off the row with the highest score, but this doesn't look very neat.

```
with open ('reportForFergusTwo.csv', 'r') as highScore:
            highScoreFinder=highScore
            valid3=False
            for row in highScoreFinder:
                if subjectInput in row:
                    if difficultyInput in row:
                        if ('10' or '9' or '8' or '7' or '6' or '5' or '4' or '3' or '2' or '1') in row:
                            valid3=True
                            print("The highest score for this quiz is:",row)
```

For example: it says, "The highest score for this quiz is: chemistry,easy,10,Luc16" but I would prefer it to say something like "The highest score for this quiz is: 10" and "This score was achieved by: Luc16", rather than just printing the whole row off, with unnecessary details like what the quiz was on.

My CSV file looks like this:

```
Subject,Difficulty,Score,Username
language,easy,10,Luc16
chemistry,easy,10,Luc16
maths,easy,9,Luc16
chemistry,easy,5,Eri15
chemistry,easy,6,Waf1
chemistry,easy,0,Eri15
```

I thought that maybe if I could find a way to take the individual results (the score and username) and put them into their own individual variables, then it would be much easier to present it the way I want, and be able to reference them later on in the function if I need them to be displayed again.

I'm just fairly new to coding and curious if this can be done, so I can improve the appearance of my code.

Edit: To solve the issue, I used str.split() to break up the indivudal fields in the rows of my CSV, so that they could be selected and held by a variable. The accepted answer shows the solution I used, but this is my final code in case this wasn't clear

```
with open ('details.csv', 'r') as stalking:
        stalkingReader=csv.reader(stalking)
        valid4=False
        for column in stalkingReader:
            if user in column[3]:
                valid4=True
                print("Here are the details for user {}... ".format(user))
                splitter=row.split(',')
                name=splitter[0]
                age=splitter[1]
                year=splitter[2]
                print("Name: {}".format(name))
                print("Age: {}".format(age))
                print("Year Group: {}".format(year))
                postReport()
    if valid4==False:
        print("Sorry Fergus, this user doesn't seem to be in our records.")
```

Comment: Just a quick note - most posts on Stack Overflow from students are unclear, too broad or lazy. The above however is well-written, clear, has a stated objective, and does not assume the user can see your screen. Hope to see you posting more here!

Comment: Erin, just spotted your update. However, we prefer answers to be posted below, rather than being merged with the question. Would you [roll that back here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49036842/revisions) and copy+paste below? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.split()` to break up the rows of your CSV so that you can individually reference the fields:

```
split_row = row.split(',')
score = split_row[2]
user = split_row[3]
print("The highest score for this quiz is: " + score)
print("This score was achieved by: " + user)
```

Comment: That's great, thanks, just tried it. I'll accept the answer when it gives me the option to (in eight minutes) :)

Comment: It wasn't my doing (I upvoted but it didn't count as I don't have enough reputation points), I think it was the person giving the second answer

Comment: @ErinJones That's alright. Glad I could help you, Erin :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("reportForFergusTwo.csv", "r") as highScore:

    subject = []
    difficulty = []
    score = []
    name = []
    for line in highScore:
        subject.append(line.split(',')[0])
        difficulty.append(line.split(',')[1])
        score.append(line.split(',')[2])
        name.append(line.split(',')[3])

    ind = score.index(max(score)

    print("The highest score for this quiz is: ", max(score))
    print("This was achieved by ", name[ind])
```

`with` opens (and will close) the `.csv` file.
Then, four empty lists are created.
Next, I loop through every line in the file, and I split every line using a comma as the delimiter. This produces a list of four elements, which are appended to each list.

Comment: @halfer Will do!

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv library

```
import csv                                                                      

with open("data", "r") as f:                                                                         
    reader = csv.reader(f)                                                         
    # skip header                                                                  
    reader.next()                                                                  
    # organize data in 2D array                                                    
    data = [ [ sub, dif, int(score), name ] for sub, dif, score, name in reader ]
    # sort by score                                                                
    data.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)                                    
    # pretty print                                                                 
    print "The highest score for this quiz is:", data[0][2]                        
    print "This score was achieved by:", data[0][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

To solve the issue, I used str.split() to break up the indivudal fields in the rows of my CSV, so that they could be selected and held by a variable. The accepted answer shows the solution I used, but this is my final code in case this wasn't clear

```
with open ('details.csv', 'r') as stalking:
        stalkingReader=csv.reader(stalking)
        valid4=False
        for column in stalkingReader:
            if user in column[3]:
                valid4=True
                print("Here are the details for user {}... ".format(user))
                splitter=row.split(',')
                name=splitter[0]
                age=splitter[1]
                year=splitter[2]
                print("Name: {}".format(name))
                print("Age: {}".format(age))
                print("Year Group: {}".format(year))
                postReport()
    if valid4==False:
        print("Sorry Fergus, this user doesn't seem to be in our records.")
```